# non-www to www ingress Nginx EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

Currently, I've worked on EKS and used nginx-ingress. The problem that I've faced is re-direct non-www to www. I read the questions in StackOverflow and followed the solution, but I've still not solve my problem. I reach out for anyone who expert in this field and any new idea. Here's my yaml file and output. Thank you for your time.

```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1'''
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: echo-ingress
     annotations:
       cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
 spec:
   tls:
   - hosts:
     - "www.boo.com"
     - "boo.com"
     secretName: tls-secret1
  rules:
    - host: "www.boo.com"
      http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: apache-php1
              port:
                number: 80
```

**the output**

**kubectl describe ingress echo-ingress**

Name: echo-ingress

Labels:

Namespace: default

Address:

Ingress Class:

Default backend:

TLS:
tls-secret1 terminates www.boo.com,boo.com

Rules:

Host                Path  Backends

---

[www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com)
/   apache-php1:80 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80)

Annotations:

cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: true
Events:
Type    Reason             Age   From                      Message

---

Normal  Sync               6s    nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
Normal  CreateCertificate  6s    cert-manager              Successfully created Certificate "tls-secret1"

Comment: Hi all, the problem is DNS in Route53 that I did not add www in record.